# Which word is more used: "vertrauen" or "trauen"?

Tags: usage

Both mean "to trust".
But which is more used in speaking?

Comment: I'd guess "vertrauen", but have no proof. Also, I would guess, that "trauen" is typically used in negative statements such as "Ich traue ihm nicht über den Weg" or variations of it, while "vertrauen" might be more often used in  positive statements. Note that "trauen" has a few other meanings besides "to trust".

Comment: Please clarify: is this more about language use in general, including writing, or with a focus on speaking/talking? Is this about absolute word usage or specifically when using *only* with the intended meaning of *"to trust"*?

Answer (score 5):

There is a slight danger here in assuming that both words are perfect synonyms. They are not. You can always exchange *trauen* for *vertrauen* insofar as both mean *"to trust"*. But you cannot exchange *vertrauen* for *trauen* insofar as *trauen* can have some other meanings like *to dare,* *to wed* etc. Also *das Vertrauen* might be a capitalised noun, but *trauen* like in *Menschen trauen sich* is always a verb.

Looking at the books corpus the evil search engine has accumulated the case seems quite clear:

> [image: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trauen%2C+vertrauen&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3]

But this is disregarding the aforementioned possible dissimilarities and just counting words in books. Assuming you are only interested in usage frequency for equivalents of *"to trust"* the situation is much more difficult.

Looking at a  German newspaper corpus based on material crawled in 2011:

> [**Word: vertrauen Number of occurrences: 4,260 Rank: 8,285 Frequency class: 11**](http://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=vertrauen)
>   See also: Vertrauen, VERTRAUEN 
>   Part of speech: Verb
>   Baseform of: vertraute, vertrauten, vertraut, vertraue
>   Part of: vertrauen auf, Kunden vertrauen, vertrauen schenken, vertrauen mit, auf etwas vertrauen, auf jemanden vertrauen
>
> Synonym: trauen, erweisen, anvertrauen

---

> [**Word: trauen Number of occurrences: 4,241 Rank: 8,311 Frequency class: 11**](http://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=trauen)
>   See also: Trauen
>  
>   Part of speech: Verb
>   Baseform of: trauten, Trau, traut, traute
>   Part of: nicht trauen, sich nicht trauen, nicht über den Weg trauen, sich etwas trauen, sich trauen lassen, seinen Ohren nicht trauen, seinen Augen kaum trauen, Seinen Augen nicht trauen, seinen Ohren kaum trauen, seinen eigenen Augen trauen
>
> Hyphenation: trau|en
>   Description: Glauben schenken 
>   Synonym: vertrauen, heiraten, getrauen, riskieren, wagen, unterfangen,  verheiraten, verehelichen, unterstehen, ehelichen, erdreisten, vermählen, verlassen

I conclude from these numbers that *vertrauen* has an advantage, but that the difference in actual usage is not so big.
If this question is meant to inquire about which verb would sound more natural when speaking, then it seems much more important check for two other things:

1. Possible double meanings. These are unlikely to occur with *vertrauen.*
2. More frequent pairings of words (collocations). If *"you do not trust your own eyes,* it would sound sightly weird to use *"Du vertraust deinen eigenen Augen nicht,"*. That would mark you as a non-native speaker or someone with a special philosophy (esotericism, buddhism, jedi…). More natural in most of these cases involving eyesight would be to choose *"Du traust deinen eigenen Augen nicht"* .

Comment: I am confused. If ngram includes all meanings of "trauen" and the German newspaper corpus only those that mean "trust", why are the numbers closer in the second case?

Comment: Irritierenderweise stehen im Suchfeld 2 Wörter, case-insensitive ist markiert, aber der Graph zeigt 4 offenbar sensitive Verläufe. Der Frager hat sicher auch 'ich traue, du traust, ... ich traute, ' usw. im Blick. Das muss nicht eng mit dem Infinitiv korrelieren. Vor allem aber - das streifst Du nur -  war nach Sprechen gefragt, nicht nach Schreiben. Das kann NGram nicht beantworten, und Gesprochenes weicht oft massiv von Geschriebenem ab.

Comment: @userunknown Ob in der Q wirklich "vor allem" Gesprochenes gemeint ist, bezweifele ich etwas. Dem Infinitiveinwand stimme ich bedingt zu, nur: Warum eigentlich sollten gebeugte Formen signifikant anderes Verteilungsmuster haben?  Zur Irritationsauflösung: case-insensitive wurde gesucht, das findet halt beides (bzw alle vier Varianten). Case-sensitive dann in der Darstellung differenziert (right click), weil dadurch hoffentlich die meisten Fälle von Substantiv, also *Vertrauen* sichtbar werden. Satzanfang dürfte ja ähnlich verteilt sein.

Comment: Nun ja - ich habe NGram nicht empfohlen, daher muss ich keine der beiden Ansichten vertreten. Ich vertrete auch nicht die Ansicht, die Verteilung weiche ab, aber solange man keine guten Gründe hat, das auszuschließen, darf man es m.E. nicht tun. Der Verwender einer Methode muss diese rechtfertigen. Zum Haupteinwand: Warum würde jemand fragen "But which is more used in speaking?", wenn er "But which is more used?" meint? Und wie verhält sich das, was von der Googlesuche erfasst wird, zum Gesprochenen? Von mir ist noch nichts erfasst, gesprochen habe ich aber schon massig. So geht's den meisten.

Comment: Selbst wenn es also egal wäre, ob gesprochen oder geschrieben, ist äußert fraglich ob die Googleergebnisse signifikant für die Fragestellung sind.

Comment: @userunknown Ich betrachte sie auch nur als ein hilfreiches Indiz. Was wäre signifikant?

Comment: Ja, falsches Wort, 'representativ' wäre das richtige gewesen. Pardon.